# Deep Copy and Shallow Copy Java

Tags: java, arrays, shallow-copy

I am studying for a java exam and what I found out practically differed from what is taught in theory.

Below is code:

```
    StringBuilder num3[]= new StringBuilder[2];
    num3[0]= new StringBuilder("Pine");
    num3[1]= new StringBuilder("Oak");
    StringBuilder num4[] = new StringBuilder[2];
    System.arraycopy(num3, 0, num4, 0, 2);
    System.out.println(num3[0]==num4[0]);
    System.out.println(num4[0]);
    num3[0] = new StringBuilder("Choc"); 
    System.out.println(num3[0]);
    System.out.println(num4[0]);
```

The output is:

```
true
Pine
Choc
Pine
```

The true statement indicates that it is a shallow copy as num4[0] references the same object of num3[0]. But when I change the num3[0] I expected num4[0] to change too.

Why would this be happening if it is a shallow copy?

Is it because the new object is being created for num3[0] and the old "Pine" StringBuilder object is being referenced by the num4 array?

If so could anyone give me an example for System.arraycopy where this shallow copy is evident?

Thanks in advance,
Chrisyopher

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the `System.arraycopy`, the two arrays are indeed shallow copies of each other. That is, you had a copy of the *references* to the `StringBuilder`s. The objects referred to are the same.

```
num3:  [ refA, refB ]                        num4: [ refA, refB ]
           |    |                                      |     |
           |    `-------> StringBuilder("Oak") <-------+-----' 
           `------------> StringBuilder("Pine") <------'
```

But then you change the *reference* in `num3[0]` to point to a new `StringBuilder`:

```
num3:  [ refC, refB ]                        num4: [ refA, refB ]
           |    |                                      |     |
           |    `-------> StringBuilder("Oak") <-------+-----' 
           |              StringBuilder("Pine") <------'
           `------------> StringBuilder("Choc")
```

The underlying objects haven't changed. All you've done is changed what's referencing them.

---

`System.arraycopy` is just like having a `for` loop that copies the values in the arrays over, except it's much more efficient for large arrays (as modern CPUs have special instructions for bulk memory copying). You don't ever need it *semantically*; it's just a performance optimisation.

Comment: References are _very_ much like pointers, except you can't do arithmetic on them and they keep what they refer to alive in the memory management system.

Answer (score 1):

`num3[0]` and `num4[0]` are references to same object, so when you change the `num3[0]` it just changes where the `num3[0]` is pointing to and will not change where `num4[0]` is pointing.

```
System.out.println(num3[0]==num4[0]);
```

This returns true because both are pointing to same object but both are individual.

If you would have done something like

`num3[0].append("something")` and then you would have printed `num3[0]` and `num4[0]` then both would have been affected.

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing num3[0], you are pointing it at something else, namely, a new StringBuilder object. num3[0] and num4[0] no longer point at the same object, hence why num4[0] doesn't change. The values of the references of the array are copied, but if you modify those values it won't affect the other array. What would affect it is if you modify the **objects** at which they point, not the **references** to those objects.

Think of `num3[0]` and `num4[0]` as two guys pointing at a bagpack.
If you add stuff to the backpack, they will both point at something that has been changed. However, if you ask `num3[0]` to point at a TV, num4[0] will still be pointing at the backpack.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because the new object is being created for num3[0] and the old
>   "Pine" StringBuilder object is being referenced by the num4 array?

Exactly.

> If so could anyone give me an example for System.arraycopy where this shallow copy is evident?

I am not sure I understand this question. No copy, be it shallow or deep can have an influence on what you do **after** the copy.

But try the following:

```
num3[1].append("tree");
println(num4[1]);        // should be "Oaktree"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried append and saw that they were obviously pointing the the same object in memory. But that made things somewhat more complicated as Arrays.copyOf is supposed to be a deep copy, but it seems to be appending the tree in num4 now. Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: No, it is not a deep copy. Who said it was?

Comment: Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 7 Programmer study guide by Richard M Reese.

Comment: @HereToLearn You should trust the API doc first and foremost and it says: `For all indices that are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will contain identical values` In a deep copy, the point would be that the object identities got lost (by cloning the onjects, and theri subobects). From this alone one can conclude that it is not a deep copy: because, how should the JVM know how to deep copy some arbitrary object? Note that the element type is **not** restricted to be Cloneable or Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

A shallow copy in this case is nothing else than a new reference to the object.
You have the object `Pine` with one pointer to it stored int `num3`. Now you make a shallow copy (you create a new reference) that is stored in `num4`. You now have one `Pine` object with two references. When you assign `Choc` to `num3` the number of references decreases by 1 and you effectively replaced the reference held by `num3` with a different one. `Pine` was never changed in any way.